# Разные ответы на команды в TelegramBot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram

Пишу *бота в Telegram* на **Python**. Работаю с библиотекой **pyTelegramBotAPI**.

**Дано:** квест-бот. На каждое задание от него можно получить подсказку нажимая либо команду */hint*, либо кнопку *"Подсказка"*.

**Задача:** ответить разными подсказками при разных заданиях.

То, что написал:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def handle_text(message):
    user_markup = telebot.types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(1)
    user_markup.row("A", "B")
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, constants.start, reply_markup=user_markup)


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):

    if message.text == "A":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Task 1, /hint")
    elif message.text == "/hint":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Hint 1")


@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])
def handle_text(message):

    if message.text == "B":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Task 2, /hint")
    elif message.text == "/hint":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Hint 2")
```

Конечно, такой код не идёт, поставил его для примера, чтобы было понятно, чего я добиваюсь.

На вторую команду бот не реагирует:

[image: На вторую команду бот не реагирует]

Comment: И в чем ваша проблема?

Comment: Добавьте вывод ошибок, если они у вас, конечно, есть.

Comment: @aapproximatenumber добавил поведение бота. Он не реагирует на вторую команду

Comment: Функция `handle_text` должна быть одна. В ней – перебор возможных сообщений: ` if message == 'A': ... elif message == 'B': ...`.

Answer (score 1):

Вот мой вариант

```
import telebot 
from telebot import types
import shelve
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def start(mess):
    chat_id = mess.chat.id
    db = shelve.open('shelve')
    db[str(chat_id)] = 'init'
    db.close()
    markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
    btn_a = types.KeyboardButton('A')
    btn_b = types.KeyboardButton('B')
    markup.add(btn_a, btn_b)
    bot.send_message(chat_id, 'Привет', reply_markup = markup)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda mess: mess.text=='B' and mess.content_type=='text')
def b(mess):
    chat_id = mess.chat.id
    db = shelve.open('shelve')
    state = db[str(chat_id)]
    if state != 'init':
        start(mess)#или какая-нибудь функция 
    else:
        db[str(chat_id)] = 'B'
        db.close()
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        btn_hint = types.KeyboardButton('Подсказка')
        markup.add(btn_hint)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'B', reply_markup = markup)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda mess: mess.text=='A' and mess.content_type=='text')
def a(mess):
    chat_id = mess.chat.id
    db = shelve.open('shelve')
    state = db[str(chat_id)]
    if state != 'init':
        start(mess)#или какая-нибудь функция 
    else:
        db[str(chat_id)] = 'A'
        db.close()
        markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup()
        btn_hint = types.KeyboardButton('Подсказка')
        markup.add(btn_hint)
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'A', reply_markup = markup)
@bot.message_handler(func=lambda mess: mess.text == 'Подсказка' and mess.content_type == 'text')
def hint(mess):
    chat_id = mess.chat.id
    db = 'shelve'.open('shelve')
    state = db[str(chat_id)]
    if state == 'init':
        pass
    elif state == 'B':
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'hint B')
    elif state == 'A':
        bot.send_message(chat_id, 'hint A')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    bot.polling(True)
```